# How do I find the total size of a stream that I just uploaded to S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On a Node.js server I am uploading a stream to S3. Here is a simplified example:

```js
import S3 from "aws-sdk/clients/s3"

const s3 = new S3({ accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, region })

async function uploadStream(key, stream) {
  const upload = s3.upload({
    Body: stream,
    Bucket: clientFiles,
    Key: key,
  })

  const result = await upload.promise()
  return result // { Bucket, ETag, Key, Location }
}
```

Since I am using a stream, I don't know the total size when the upload is initiated, and the upload result doesn't give me anything more than Bucket, ETag, Key, & Location values.

How can I get the total size of the uploaded stream?

Answer (score 1):

How about use `ManagedUpload` and `httpUploadProgress`?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#httpUploadProgress-event

```js
async function uploadStream(key, stream) {
  const upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
      Body: stream,
      Bucket: clientFiles,
      Key: key
    }
  });
  upload.on("httpUploadProgress", function(progress) {
    console.log(progress.total);
  });
  ...
```

Comment: Nice. I did find that recently and while it's not ideal, I think it's the best the package can offer. Thanks!